# How do I convert my Objective-C app to Automatic Reference Counting?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I would like to convert my iOS 4 application to use the Automatic Reference Counting in iOS 5.

So far I think I have to go through all the files and remove any `retain`, `release`, or `autorelease`. But to be sure I want to ask first.

- Do I have to do it manually? How?
- Is there a tool from Apple or anybody else?

Answer (score 1):

You want this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in XCode 4.2 and select the following menu option:

**Edit** > **Refactor** > **Convert to Objective-C ARC...**